# Enemies path to position off NavRegion and not to set target

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

### Godot Version

4.2.1 w/ Jolt Physics

### Problem and context

Hello! I have a prototype 3D scene where I am trying to get enemies to path to a car and the enemies are attempting to path to a point off the navmesh (-9.201, -0.181171, -85.30832). I have set the target location to be the $Vehicle in the scene (or so I thought) but the agents are attempting to get to a different coordinate.

I am not sure why this is the case and at a loss of how to debug.

My goal is to have the enemies/agents always path to the car no matter its location on the oval track.

What additional information can I provide or find to help debug?

**Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks!**

---

*[Enemies attempting to path off nav mesh]*
[image]
*[Nav Region settings]*
[image]
*[Nav Agent settings]*
[image]

### Code Snippets

#### zombie.gd

```
extends CharacterBody3D

@export_group("Zombie Stats")
@export var movement_speed: float = 4.0
@export var Health = 1

@onready var collision_shape = $CollisionShape3D
@onready var nav_agent = $NavigationAgent3D
@onready var movement_target = %Vehicle

func _physics_process(delta):
    var current_location = global_transform.origin
    var next_location = nav_agent.get_next_path_position()
    var new_velocity = (next_location - current_location).normalized() * movement_speed
    
    velocity = velocity.move_toward(new_velocity, .25)
    move_and_slide()

func update_target_location(target_location):
    nav_agent.target_position = target_location
```

world.gd

```
extends Node3D

@onready var car = $Vehicle

func _physics_process(delta):
    get_tree().call_group("Enemies", "update_target_location", car.global_transform.origin)
    print(car.global_transform.origin)
```